# How to make React Router Dom 6.8 send request after Keycloak auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router-dom, keycloak

I have a web app with React JS Front, .NEt API & Keycloak for Identity Provider.
So, the user connect via KeyCloak, and is redirected on the front with a JWT, that is send to the API through Axios request interceptors. So far, so good.
On the front, React Router V6 is installed, with createBrowserRouter, and loaders.
My problem is, on the homepage, the request of the loader is sended so far, that the interceptor can't get the request and send the JWT, so I get a 401.
I tried to temporize with tests, loadings, but nothing works. I can't figure out.

### index.tsx

```js
/*----- IMPORTS -----*/
import App from './App';
import './styles/index.scss';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { MantineProvider } from '@mantine/core';
import { ModalsProvider } from '@mantine/modals';
import { NotificationsProvider } from '@mantine/notifications';

/*----- KEYCLOAK IMPORTS-----*/
import { ReactKeycloakProvider } from '@react-keycloak/web';
import keycloak from './keycloak/keycloak';
import { AxiosInterceptor } from './keycloak/Api';

/*----- STORE REDUX IMPORTS -----*/
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import store, { persistor } from './redux/store';
import MantineConfig from './ressources/Mantineconfig';

/*----- ROOT RENDER DOM -----*/
const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container!);

root.render(
  <ReactKeycloakProvider
      authClient={keycloak}
      initOptions={{ 
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        checkLoginIframe: false
      }}  
  >
    <AxiosInterceptor>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <MantineProvider withCSSVariables theme={MantineConfig}>
            <ModalsProvider>
              <NotificationsProvider
                position='bottom-right'
                zIndex={2000}
                containerWidth={300}
              >
                <App />
              </NotificationsProvider>
            </ModalsProvider>
          </MantineProvider>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </AxiosInterceptor>
  </ReactKeycloakProvider>
)
```

### App.tsx

```js
import ScrollToTop from './components/ScrollToTop';
import { RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import { router } from './utils/Routes';

function App() {

  return (
    <>

          <div className="ContentContainer">
            <ScrollToTop />
            <RouterProvider router={router} />
          </div>
      
    
    </> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

### Routes.tsx *(loaders are here, I cut some routes and delete imports, that was heavy)*

```js
export const router = createBrowserRouter([

    {
        path:"/",
        element: <Layout/> ,
        children:[
            {
                index: true,
                element: <Home/>,
                loader: homeLoader
            },
            {
                path: "marques",
                element: <Marques />,
                loader: brandLoader
            },
            {
                path: "marques/:id",
                element: <Marque />,
                loader: ({params}) => {
                    return singleBrandLoader(params.id)
                }
            },
            {
                path: "approbations",
                element: <Approbations />
            },
            {
                path: "catalogue",
                element: <Catalogue />,
                loader: catalogLoader
            },
            {
                path: 'panier', 
                element: <Panier />
            },
            {
                path: 'familles', 
                element: <Familles />,
                loader: familleLoader
            },
            {
                path: 'familles/:id', 
                element: <Famille />,
                loader: ({params}) => {
                    return singleFamilyLoader(params.id)
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'formations', 
                element: <Formations />,
                loader: ({params}) => {
                    return formationsLoader()
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'produits/:id', 
                element: <Produits />,
                loader: ({params}) => {
                   return productLoader(params.id)
                }
            }
            {
                path: '/error/:id',
                element: <Error/>
            },
            {
                path: "*", 
                element: <Navigate to='error/404' replace /> 
            }
        ]
    }
])
```

### AxiosInterceptor.tsx

```js
import { useKeycloak } from "@react-keycloak/web";
import axios, { InternalAxiosRequestConfig, RawAxiosRequestHeaders  } from "axios";
import { useEffect } from "react";

// Création d'un instance Axios qui permettra de renvoyer
// à chaque requête les tokens Keycloak via les interceptors
const API = axios.create({
    headers: {'X-gravitee-api-key': process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY }
});

/**
 * Wrapper des interceptors
 */
const AxiosInterceptor = ({children}) => {
    
    const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();

    useEffect(() => {

        // Création du handler de requests qui récupère le token courant
        // si l'authentification est fonctionnelle, on ajoute le token
        // dans les headers
        
        const handleRequest = ( config: InternalAxiosRequestConfig ) => {
            console.log('HELLO')
            
            if(keycloak?.authenticated){
                let token = keycloak.token;
                config["headers"] = config.headers ?? {};
                (config.headers as RawAxiosRequestHeaders)["Authorization"] = `Bearer ` + token;
            } else {
                console.log('GOODBYE')
            }
            return config;
        }

        // Handler d'erreurs
        const handleError = ( error: any ) => {
            console.log('ERROR HERE')
            Promise.reject(error)
        };

        // Application des handlers sur les interceptors de request
        const requestInterceptors = API.interceptors.request.use(handleRequest, handleError);

        // Et ensuite on ejecte proprement
        return () => {
            API.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptors);
        }

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [])

    return children;
}

export default API;
export { AxiosInterceptor };
```

### Layout.tsx

```js
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import Footer from "./Footer"
import Header from "./Header"
import GoToTop from "./GoToTop"
import { KeycloakUserProvider } from "../keycloak/Context"
import { useHandleMenu } from "../utils/useHandleMenu"
import { useKeycloak } from "@react-keycloak/web"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import CustomLoader from "../utils/CustomLoader"

const Layout = () => {
  const [opened,, toggle] = useHandleMenu();
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();
  const isAuth = keycloak.authenticated;
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState<boolean>(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(isAuth){
      setVisible(true)
    }
    if(!isAuth ){
      setVisible(false)
    }
  }, [isAuth, navigate])

  return (

    visible ? ( <CustomLoader /> )
    : (
    <KeycloakUserProvider>
      <GoToTop />

        <Header 
          opened={opened}
          toggle={toggle}
        />
        <Outlet />
        <Footer />
        
    </KeycloakUserProvider>
    )
  )
}

export default Layout
```